# Passing column in subquery is not working

Tags: mysql

Please take a look at my query

```
SELECT ht_tutor.id
    ,(
        SELECT group_concate(days)
        FROM (
            SELECT fkTutorId
                ,days
                ,(
                    CASE 
                        WHEN endTime <= '14:00:00'
                            THEN '00:00:00'
                        WHEN TIMEDIFF(startTime, '14:00:00') < '00:00:00' && TIMEDIFF('17:00:00', endTime) < '00:00:00'
                            THEN TIMEDIFF('17:00:00', '14:00:00')
                        ELSE '00:00:00'
                        END
                    ) AS intersect_time
            FROM ht_tutorAvailablity
            WHERE ht_tutorAvailablity.fkTutorId = ht_tutor.id
            ) AS avail_table
        ) AS days_avail
FROM ht_tutor 
LIMIT 0,10
```

> ERROR: #1054 - Unknown column 'ht_tutor.id' in 'where clause'

How can I pass `ht_tutor.id` their ?

If I'm passing `tutor_id` manually like `ht_tutorAvailablity.fkTutorId = "12"` than it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you need to use `JOIN` in your scenario. The below query will JOIN with the `TUT.id = AVA.fkTutorId` condition:

```
SELECT group_concate(days), id
FROM (
    SELECT AVA.fkTutorId, AVA.days, TUT.id
            CASE 
            WHEN AVA.endTime <= '14:00:00'
                THEN '00:00:00'
            WHEN TIMEDIFF(AVA.startTime, '14:00:00') < '00:00:00' && TIMEDIFF('17:00:00', AVA.endTime) < '00:00:00'
                THEN TIMEDIFF('17:00:00', '14:00:00')
            ELSE '00:00:00'
            END AS intersect_time
    FROM ht_tutorAvailablity AVA
    JOIN ht_tutor TUT ON TUT.id = AVA.fkTutorId
) AS avail_table 
LIMIT 0, 10
```